# adb or monkeyrunner? Which is more stable?

Tags: adb, monkeyrunner, stability

I'm using National Instruments Teststand to set up some sequences for automating an android device.  I'm using a combination of direct adb.exe calls, and monkeyrunner calls to .py scripts.
When I am settin up a sequence to say automate some touch commands on a device, I have a choice of either using a seqeuence of "adb shell input tap" commands, or calling a single .py script to automate these actions using "device.press" and "device.touch" functions.  Is one preferred over the other for any reason?  Is one any more stable?  All things equal I kind of prefer the monkeyrunner script just because it seems a little more flexible and readable.  But if adb is more stable I'd opt that way when possible. This is going to be a test that runs for >24 hours doing repeated operations so stability is my first goal.
Thanks for any input
David Jenkinson

Answer (score 0):

`adb` is more stable and reliable for long running tests. Fortunately you don't have to choose between `adb` or python scripts because [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) provides the necessary bindings to invoke (most) adb commands from python.